# Stanford NER prop file meaning of DistSim

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

In one of the example .prop files coming with the Stanford NER software there are two options I do not understand:

```
useDistSim = true
distSimLexicon = /u/nlp/data/pos_tags_are_useless/egw4-reut.512.clusters
```

Does anyone have a hint what DistSim stands for and where I can find any more documentation on how to use these options?

UPDATE: I just found out that DistSim means distributional similarity. I still wonder what that means in this context.

Comment: Stanford has a whole bunch of undocumented and unused options. These were probably meant for some experiment a long time ago and someone forgot to remove them.

Comment: Thanks, but this one is in the example file, so it might be nice to know what it does. I also find that training takes very very long and uses lots of iterations, is there a way to limit these?

Comment: The options for NER are neatly document in https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/NERFeatureFactory.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"DistSim" refers to using features based on word classes/clusters, built using distributional similarity clustering methods (e.g., Brown clustering, exchange clustering). Word classes group words which are similar, semantically and/or syntactically, and allow an NER system to generalize better, including handling words not in the training data of the NER system better. Many of our distributed models use a distributional similarity clustering features as well as word identity features, and gain significantly from doing so.  In Stanford NER, there are a whole bunch of flags/properties that affect how distributional similarity is interpreted/used: `useDistSim`, `distSimLexicon`, `distSimFileFormat`, `distSimMaxBits`, `casedDistSim`, `numberEquivalenceDistSim`, `unknownWordDistSimClass`, and you need to look at the code in `NERFeatureFactory.java` to decode the details, but in the simple case, you just need the first two, and they need to be used while training the model, as well as at test time.  The default format of the lexicon is just a text file with a series of lines with two tab separated columns of `word clusterName`. The cluster names are arbitrary.